# Gemfile conflict version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to install an open source project ruby on rails

I am getting the error in the following screenshot, I am new in Ruby on rails, Can anyone help please?

[image]

Comment: you need either raise nokogiri version to which one supports Ruby 2.7.x, or switch to Ruby below 2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix, go to your gemfile and disable `nokogiri` then `bundle install`

the error will disappear, if you need nokogiri, you will downgrade your version of ruby